# Custom extraLogger not getting [success] messages in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using the following code to hook into SBT's logging system to send the logging messages to another process accessible via a `server` setting:

```
extraLoggers := {
  val clientLogger = FullLogger {
    new Logger {
      def log(level: Level.Value, message: => String): Unit =
        if(level >= Level.Info) server.value.send(Json.arr("print", level.toString(), message))
      def success(message: => String): Unit = server.value.send(Json.arr("print", "info", message))
      def trace(t: => Throwable): Unit = server.value.send(Json.arr("print", "error", t.toString))
    }
  }
  val currentFunction = extraLoggers.value
  (key: ScopedKey[_]) => clientLogger +: currentFunction(key)
}
```

When I look at the output being spewed out on the other `server` process, I don't see the messages with green `[success]` tags appearing. Everything else (i.e. all the `[info]` messages and the red `[error]` messages) appear just fine.

Printing out `clientLogger.successEnabled` gives me `true`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tested your `extraLoggers` with a custom task that spits `streams.value.log.success("Succezz")` and it worked fine - the corresponding `success` implementation was called with `message` input parameter. Could that be that `server.value.send` doesn't work for all levels?! How do you test the `extraLoggers`?

Comment: `server.value.send` works, and you're right that `streams.value.log.success` works. I suspect the problem is that the successes that I am expecting (i.e. the `[success] compilation took 5 seconds` messages) aren't being passed through `extraLoggers`

Comment: That reflects my sentiments. extraLoggers are picked up for `log` messages, but somehow `showSuccess` and `showTiming` don't get passed through the loggers. I'm searching the sources for confirmation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: Please use with care as the answer might be incomplete or even totally wrong.

After consulting [the sources of sbt](https://github.com/sbt/sbt) my understanding is that `extraLoggers` is a setting that is only ["A function that provides additional loggers for a given setting."](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala#L34) and these `additional loggers` are *additional* to [StandardMain.console](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Main.scala#L62).

*If it were possible*, you would therefore have to set [logManager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala#L35) to have a reference to `extraLoggers` and your own custom [sbt.ConsoleOut](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/util/log/src/main/scala/sbt/ConsoleOut.scala) in `build.sbt`, e.g.

```
logManager := LogManager.defaults(extraLoggers.value, new ConsoleOut {
  val lockObject = System.out
  def print(s: String): Unit = synchronized { print(s) }
  def println(s: String): Unit = synchronized { println(s) }
  def println(): Unit = synchronized {
    System.out.println()
  }
})
```

It won't however work since `sbt.ConsoleOut` is a sealed trait and hence there is no way to use it outside the file it was defined.

Having said that, I believe, in `sbt 0.13.1`, it's not possible to "intercept" the `[success]` message that's printed out when `showSuccess` is `true` as it comes out from `ConsoleOut` that's outside your control.

What you can do with `extraLoggers` is to have your own custom logging for tasks and `streams.value.log.success("Succezz")` should work.

The sample `build.sbt` with `extraLoggers` and a `t` task to demo the custom logger.

```
extraLoggers := {
  val clientLogger = FullLogger {
    new Logger {
      def log(level: Level.Value, message: => String): Unit =
        if(level >= Level.Info) println(s"+++ $message at $level")
      def success(message: => String): Unit = println(s"+++ success: $message")
      def trace(t: => Throwable): Unit = println(s"+++ trace: throwable: $t")
    }
  }
  val currentFunction = extraLoggers.value
  (key: ScopedKey[_]) => clientLogger +: currentFunction(key)
}

val t = taskKey[Unit]("Show extraLoggers")

t := {
  println(s"Using extraLoggers")
  val s: TaskStreams = streams.value
  val log = s.log
  log.debug("Saying hi...")
  log.info("Hello!")
  log.error("Error")
  log.success("Succezz")
}
```

With the file, executing the `t` task gives the following output:

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-0.13.1-extra-loggers/project
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1-extra-loggers (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-0.13.1-extra-loggers/)
[sbt-0-13-1-extra-loggers]> about
[info] This is sbt 0.13.1
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-0.13.1-extra-loggers/}sbt-0-13-1-extra-loggers 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.3
[info] Available Plugins: com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard, growl.GrowlingTests, org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin, np.Plugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.3
[sbt-0-13-1-extra-loggers]> t
Using extraLoggers
[info] Hello!
+++ Hello! at info
[error] Error
+++ Error at error
[success] Succezz
+++ success: Succezz
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 16, 2013 10:30:48 PM
```