# Displaying timestamp for debug mode in SBT?

Tags: sbt

My sbt update is very slow, I'd like to see what happens in details.

So, I have:

```
sbt --debug update > sbtupdate.log
```

The problem is that the log does not have timestamp for each line, how to enable it?

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, it is not possible with only SBT options. However this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507674/how-to-add-timestamp-to-stderr-redirection) provides a good solution. I will rephrase the answer for your specific case. All the following supposes a Unix OS but it should be possible to adapt it for a Windows environment (and straightforward if using Cygwin).

First, you need a script called for example `predate.sh` that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line ; do
    echo "$(date): ${line}"
done
```

The `date` command can be changed following your needs. Then, you must make this script executable with `chmod u+x predate.sh`.

Finally run your initial command and pipe the standard output to our new script:

```
sbt --debug update | ./predate.sh > sbtupdate.log
```

Please read the linked question, it contains interesting other responses.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to develop a custom logger as described in [Add a custom logger](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/logging.html#custom):

> The setting extraLoggers can be used to add custom loggers. A custom
>   logger should implement [AbstractLogger]. extraLoggers is a function
>   ScopedKey[_] => Seq[AbstractLogger]. This means that it can provide
>   different logging based on the task that requests the logger.

In the custom logger you'd prepend messages with timestamp.

```
def datedPrintln = (m: String) =>
  println(s"+++ ${java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime()} $m")

extraLoggers := {
  val clientLogger = FullLogger {
    new Logger {
      def log(level: Level.Value, message: => String): Unit =
        if(level >= Level.Info) datedPrintln(s"$message at $level")
      def success(message: => String): Unit = datedPrintln(s"success: $message")
      def trace(t: => Throwable): Unit = datedPrintln(s"trace: throwable: $t")
    }
  }
  val currentFunction = extraLoggers.value
  (key: ScopedKey[_]) => clientLogger +: currentFunction(key)
}
```

You can find out about how to develop your own logger in my answer to [Custom extraLogger not getting [success] messages in sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20621260/1305344)