# How to redirect console output of command to a file?

Tags: sbt

What are the means of redirecting output from a single command to a file in sbt?

I could exit sbt, execute `sbt mycommand > out.txt`, and start it again, but I'm wondering if there's an alternative?

Comment: Would you like to completely disable the output ala `> out.txt 2 &>1` or be able to save to a file in addition to the other streams registered ala `tee`?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Second would be better, but first is acceptable as well.

Comment: The second is simpler so I'm for it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [Add a custom logger](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Logging.html#Add+a+custom+logger) you can find more information about what's required to have a custom logger that logs to a file - use `extraLoggers` and add an instance of [sbt.AbstractLogger](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/index.html#sbt.AbstractLogger) that does the saving.

You may find my answer to [Displaying timestamp for debug mode in SBT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398788/displaying-timestamp-for-debug-mode-in-sbt/22416049#22416049) useful. The example copied here:

```
def datedPrintln = (m: String) =>
  println(s"+++ ${java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime()} $m")

extraLoggers := {
  val clientLogger = FullLogger {
    new Logger {
      def log(level: Level.Value, message: => String): Unit =
        if(level >= Level.Info) datedPrintln(s"$message at $level")
      def success(message: => String): Unit = datedPrintln(s"success: $message")
      def trace(t: => Throwable): Unit = datedPrintln(s"trace: throwable: $t")
    }
  }
  val currentFunction = extraLoggers.value
  (key: ScopedKey[_]) => clientLogger +: currentFunction(key)
}
```